# Modifying container's pair / neighbours

Tags: c++, c++11

I faced problem where I need to modify container's element basing on information stored in previous element. Example:

`If previous vector element is divisable by 2 then multiply current element by 10
vec -> [12, 11, 33, 10]`

I tried to find algorithm that nicely wraps this operation but I couldn't find it. I came with and idea but I don't really like this solution.

`check if vector's size is bigger than 1
auto last_element_it = vec.end();
--last_element_it;
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != last_element_it; ++it)
{
  auto next_element_it = it;
  ++next_element_it;
  // do whatever I want with it and next_element_it
}`

Is there any simpler and/or prettier way to do this?

@EDIT
Integers in the example are only to simplify this question. In my real issue I have class objects in my container.

Comment: So what should be the output for the input vector `[12,11,33,10]`? Think carefully, as the answer can rule out the existing answer or make it valid.

Comment: This is only example, in my real issue I have there some class objects. I added example with integers only to simplify my question.

Comment: Well, the question is important in itself, basically when you evaluate the condition on the preceding element, do you evaluate it in terms of the value before the algorithm started, or in terms of the value after the algorithm processed the previous element. The two options would yield: `[12, 110, 33, 10]` (based on initial state) or `[12, 110, 330, 100]` (based on current value after applying the operation to the previous value)

Comment: There is third answer - in my real issue operations applied does not change object's members that are used to determine if the operation is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the algorithm [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) to execute an operation for each adjacent pair. If the range is empty or consists only a single element, nothing happens.

```
std::adjacent_find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    // do something with pair of adjacent elements
    foobar(lhs, rhs);
    return false;
});
```

The operation always returns `false`, because `std::adjacent_find` would stop on the first pair for which the operation returns `true`.

---

According to the C++ standard, it's not allowed to call non-const functions on the dereferenced iterators. However, you can write your own version of `std::adjacent_find` without these limitations:

```
template <class ForwardIt, typename BinaryPredicate>
void for_each_adjacent(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p)
{
    if (first == last) {
        // nothing
    } else {
        for (ForwardIt next = std::next(first); next != last; ++next, ++first) {
            p(*first, *next);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure you are allowed to change the value in the middle of the iteration of that algorithm, and I am not sure this will solve the problem (I find the requirement ill-described). Basically after finding the first element that is even, all elements will be multiplied by 10 in this solution

Comment: 25.1  [algorithms] / 9: *The BinaryPredicate parameter [...] binary_pred shall not apply any non-constant function
through the dereferenced iterators.* So no, you cannot use `adjacent_find` to modify a sequence.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You are right. I will change the answer. Apparently, the OP is not interested in changing the dereferences iterators.

Comment: To be clear - I do want to change dereferenced iterators but I do not change members of class object (dereferenced iterator) that are reponsible for decision whether apply or not specific operation on them.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::experimental::optional<int> prev;
for( int& x : container ) {
  if (prev && ((*prev % 2)==0)) {
    x*=10;
  }
  prev = x;
}
```

using the post-C++1y [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional).  The branch ends up being highly predictable, so branch prediction failures are rare.

If you have a pile of range and container adapters lying around, I would simply write:

```
for( auto it : skip_first( as_iterators( container ) ) ) {
  auto prev = std::prev(it);
}
```

where `as_iterators` takes a range and returns an immutable range over the iterators in the range, `skip_first` takes a range and returns the range without the first element (empty if the source range is empty).

Neither of these are trivial to write, but I find writing that kind of thing a good exercise in C++ generic programming.  Remember that if you take an rvalue as input, store a `move`ed-to copy rather than an rvalue reference, so you can daisy-chain them.

Comment: `%` is not the divisible operator ;) You're missing a `!`

Comment: @leemes that's surprising

Answer (score 0):

since you're dealing with vectors, the old fashioned way is fine...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


using vec_t = std::vector<int>;

using namespace std;

void by_10_next_after_even(vec_t& vec) {
    for(size_t i = 1 ; i < vec.size() ; ++i) {
        if (0 == vec[i-1] % 2) {
            vec[i] *= 10;
            return;  // or break if you prefer
        }
    }
}

void by_10_all_after_even(vec_t& vec) {
    for (size_t i = 1 ; i < vec.size() ; ++i) {
        if (0 == (vec[i-1] % 2)) {
            for ( ; i < vec.size() ; ++i) {
                vec[i] *= 10;
            }
            return; // or break if you prefer
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vec_t test1 = { 9, 7, 3, 6, 7, 2 };

    by_10_next_after_even(test1);

    vec_t test2 = { 9, 7, 3, 6, 7, 2 };

    by_10_all_after_even(test2);

    copy(test1.begin(), test1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    copy(test2.begin(), test2.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```